# Where the native image cache is physically located in the local computer?

Tags: .net, .net-assembly

**`Ngen.exe install <appName>`** creates **native images,** which are files containing compiled processor-specific machine code, and installs them into the **native image cache** on the local computer. 
Where is the native image cache **physically** located on the local computer?

Comment: Physically, inside the hard disk or SSD or other storage medium.

Comment: @angryperson lol...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **native image cache** can be found on 
`C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64` - for **64-bit** images 

 and 
`C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32` - for **32-bit** images (for .NET 4.5).

This path is **not** accessible through Windows Explorer, so use **cmd** or a **powershell**.